# How do I install Kubernetes on Linux SUSE?

Tags: docker, suse, kubernetes

I am running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2.  I want to install Kubernetes.

I tried this command:   `zypper in kubernetes`
But I got this message:  `No provider of 'kubernetes' found.`

I downloaded this file: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP2/src/kubernetes-1.5.3-8.2.src.rpm

I used: `rpm -ivh kubernetes-1.5.3-8.2.src.rpm`

But there is no evidence that Kubernetes is installed.

I found a relevant .ymp file.

http://software.opensuse.org/ymp/Virtualization:containers/SLE_12_SP2/kubernetes.ymp

But I do not know how to use it.

How do I install Kubernetes on Linux SUSE?

Answer (score 4):

The canonical instructions are avaiable at ([Opensuse.org](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=Virtualization%3Acontainers&package=kubernetes))

The page contains install instructions for kubernetes on openSUSE and SLE 12.

Comment: There is only source code and no binary packages.

Comment: I'm on tumbleweed I can't get kubernetes running to save my life! Tried on an ubuntu 16.04 vm and it worked with no issues...

Comment: The OpenSUSE page is empty

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a `source RPM`. Source RPMs contain source code and patches as they were at the time of RPM build and a `.spec` file used to generate the RPM.

You will need to have `rpmbuild` installed on your machine if you wish to work source RPMs. Using `rpmbuild` and the `.spec` file, you can build RPM from the SRPM package.

Answer (score 0):

Try these instructions : 
https://developer.ibm.com/storage/2019/03/01/kubernetes-1-12-on-suse-linux-using-kubeadm/

they base on adding the google kubernetes repo to your SLES system.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Please review the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information regarding this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to do it with SLE 12 at this time. With SLE 15 sp 1, you can install the latest beta of SUSE CaaS Platform 4 which uses Kubeadm.

There is also a OpenSUSE kubernetes platform called OpenSUSE Kubic that is based on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.